# How to write this Objective-C delegate function in swift of NimbusKit Attributed Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

So I have this delegate function that is written in Objective-C but I'm bridging the class over to swift and can't figure out how to declare it in Swift.

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(NIAttributedLabel *)attributedLabel 
didSelectTextCheckingResult:(NSTextCheckingResult *)result atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

This is the current function that I'm trying to use unsuccessfully:

```
func didSelectTextCheckingResult(result:NSTextCheckingResult, atPoint point:CGPoint) {
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:result.URL];
}
```

Comment: What happened to the `attributedLabel` part of the name?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you've left out the first part of the name of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Objective-C expects this method:

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(NIAttributedLabel *)attributedLabel 
    didSelectTextCheckingResult:(NSTextCheckingResult *) result   
    atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

...then surely the Swift equivalent would be:

```
func attributedLabel(attributedLabel: NIAttributedLabel,
    didSelectTextCheckingResult result: NSTextCheckingResult,
    atPoint point: CGPoint) {
        // ...
}
```